# Android : How to set image with url by a subroutine

Tags: android, url, bitmap

I'm creating a subroutine to get an image using a url. Here is a similar subroutine that I used to parse text from an XML into my UI:

```
public void loading(int index) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                arrayList = XMLPullParser.parse("http://localhost/news.xml", "news", 1, 2, 3);
                //URL url = new URL("http://localhost/"+arrayList2.get(1).toString());
                //final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        chk1.setText(arrayList.get(0).toString());
                        chk2.setText(arrayList.get(1).toString());
                        chk3.setText(arrayList.get(2).toString());
                        try {
                            img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap("http://localhost/1.jpg"));
                            img2.setImageBitmap(bitmap("http://localhost/2.jpg"));
                            img3.setImageBitmap(bitmap("http://localhost/3.jpg"));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Here is the change I made to load the images:

```
static Bitmap bmp;
public Bitmap bitmap(String url_input) throws IOException {
    final String get_url = url_input;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final URL url = new URL(get_url);
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return bmp;
}
```

The subroutine works when parsing text but doesn't work properly when loading the bitmaps. I need to set images to 3 image buttons and want to use a subroutine to do it.

I know it should not use static for my `bmp` variable, it's just a test to let me know if it works.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to use a subroutine to do Bitmap this job, but it wont display my image.

Comment: How do you test the application ? Because if you are testing with your phone or emulator, in either case `localhost` will not work.

Comment: These code is success to display image, but I need to refresh this page 2 times, it will be display my image,  and I use static cause they show the same image, but I have no idea to return the bitmap in thread, I know use internet connect must use thread to do it.

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it properly show what you have already done and what you are trying to do next. I've also re-worded some of your sentences to improve clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it something like this. This asserts that you have the code in an activity. But the thread handling should probably be changes to use an AsyncTask instead.

```
bitmap(img1, "http://localhost/1.jpg");
.
.
.


public void bitmap(final ImageView imageView, String url_input) throws IOException {
    final String get_url = url_input;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final URL url = new URL(get_url);
                final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                if (bmp != null) {
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: Is this an in a Activiy? If not you have to get hold of the activity

Comment: It is a fragment page

Comment: it show another error " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps" and I delete "bmp.recycle()" this line, it is work!

Answer (score 1):

Your bitmaps are not displayed because your threading setup is incorrect. Your bitmap method returns before thread it started has finished. Also you are using static variable used by all threads.

I recommend to use AsyncTask and do all your background work there - there is no need to spawn separate threads for every image. Also pay attention to assign values to your checkboxes and images in onPostExecute method because these can be assigned only in main (gui) thread.

Comment: Thank you! And I know the reason!